# Powershell enters foreach loop with null object

Tags: powershell

I'm listing all backups in a given directory:

```
$backups = Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFilepath | 
Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-7)) -and 
(-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -like "backup*")}
```

If I set it to deliberately return no files (.addDays(-600) then the following prints "Empty" (as expected):

```
if (!$backups)
{
    "Empty"
}
```

If I try to list the names with an empty $backups variable:

```
foreach ($file in $backups)
{
    $file.FullName;
}
```

I get nothing (as expected), if I change this to:

```
"test"+ $file.FullName;
```

then I get a single "test" under the "Empty". How is this possible if $backups is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "feature" of Powershell.  Your `$backups` may contain *multiple* `$null` values, as well as non-null, so Powershell must iterate the object to process the `foreach`.  The fact the we both see `$backup` as a single-value scalar (`$null` in this case) doesn't matter, to MS at least... :)

See this [Microsoft Connect Bug Report](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/281908/foreach-should-not-execute-the-loop-body-for-a-scalar-value-of-null#) for more details -- It is "fixed" in Powershell v3.

On v2:

```
PS H:\> foreach ( $i in $null ) { "Hi" }
Hi
```

On v3:

```
PS H:\> foreach ( $i in $null ) { "Hi" }
```

(No output)

Comment: I get an output of "Hi" and my $Host.Version gives 3.2.0.2237

Comment: @SteB I cannot find that version of PowerShell -- are you using PowerGui?  Can you provide `$Host.Version` from the actual `powershell.exe` binary, or even `$PSVersionTable`?

Comment: Yes, I am using PowerGUI. My powershell.exe in WindowsPowerShell/v1.0 is 6.1.7600.16385. $PSVersionTable gives CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.17929 and WSManStackVersion: 2.0

Comment: @SteB Yep, your PowerGUI is v3.2.0.2237, your Powershell is v2.  `$PSVersionTable` should have listed `PSVersion` as well, but your `powershell.exe` binary 6.1.7600.16385 confirms v2.

Comment: You can see `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`, in particular the `$Host` section, to understand how PowerGUI is returning 3.2.0.2237 for `$Host.Version` instead of the "real" `powershell.exe` version.

Comment: It appears that I'm only running v2 (I used $psversiontable), I feel an upgrade coming on :) Thanks for your help.