# Protect foreach loop when empty list

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell v2.0 I want to delete any files older than X days:

```
$backups = Get-ChildItem -Path $Backuppath | 
                Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-$DaysKeep)) -and (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -like "backup*")}

foreach ($file in $backups)
{
    Remove-Item $file.FullName;
}
```

However, when $backups is empty I get: `Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.`

I've tried:

1. Protecting the foreach with `if (!$backups)`
2. Protecting the Remove-Item with `if (Test-Path $file -PathType Leaf)`
3. Protecting the Remove-Item with `if ([IO.File]::Exists($file.FullName) -ne $true)`

None of these seem to work, what if the recommended way of preventing a foreach loop from being entered if the list is empty?

Comment: @Dan - Tried both ($backups > 0) and (@($backups).count -gt 0), but neither work as expected when there are no files.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With Powershell 3 the `foreach` statement does not iterate over `$null` and the issue described by OP no longer occurs.

From the [Windows PowerShell Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/) post [New V3 Language Features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/):

> **ForEach statement does not iterate over $null**
>
> In PowerShell V2.0, people were often surprised by:
>
> `PS> foreach ($i in $null) { 'got here' }`
>
> `got here`
>
> This situation often comes up when a cmdlet doesn’t return any objects.  In PowerShell V3.0, you don’t need to add an if statement to avoid iterating over $null.  We take care of that for you.

For PowerShell `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -le 2` see the following for original answer.

---

You have two options, I mostly use the second.

Check `$backups` for not `$null`. A simple `If` around the loop can check for not `$null`

```
if ( $backups -ne $null ) {

    foreach ($file in $backups) {
        Remove-Item $file.FullName;
    }

}
```

Or

Initialize `$backups` as a null array.  This avoids the ambiguity of the "iterate empty array" issue [you asked about in your last question](https://serverfault.com/questions/457122/powershell-enters-foreach-loop-with-null-object).

```
$backups = @()
# $backups is now a null value array

foreach ( $file in $backups ) {
    # this is not reached.
    Remove-Item $file.FullName
}
```

Sorry, I neglected to provide an example integrating your code. Note the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet wrapped in the array. This would also work with functions which could return a `$null`.

```
$backups = @(
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Backuppath |
        Where-Object { ($_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-$DaysKeep)) -and (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -like "backup*") }
)

foreach ($file in $backups) {
    Remove-Item $file.FullName
}
```

Comment: I've used the first one (it's easier to understand), I couldn't get the second one to work (I was probably doing something wrong).

Comment: @SteB You're correct, my example was poorly explained (it still is), but I've provided an edit including your example code.  For a better explanation of the behavior, please see [this post on Keith Hill's blog](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/effective-powershell-item-8-output-cardinality-scalars-collections-and-empty-sets-oh-my/), he is not only a PowerShell expert, but also a far better writer than me.  [Keith is active on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/153982/keith-hill), I would encourage you (or anyone interested in PS) to check out his stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I'd like to point out that the `ForEach-Objec` cmdlet doesn't suffer the same issue as using the `ForEach` key word.  So you can pipe the results of `DIR` to `ForEach` and just reference the file using $_, like:

```
$backups | ForEach{ Remove-Item $_ }
```

You can actually forward the Dir command itself through the pipe and avoid even assigning the variable like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Backuppath | 
Where-Object {
             ($_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-$DaysKeep)) -and `
             (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -like "backup*")
             } |
ForEach{ Remove-Item $_ }
```

I added line breaks for readability.

I understand some people like ForEach/In for readability. Sometimes `ForEach-Object` can get a little hairy, especially if you are nesting as it gets hard to follow the `$_` reference.  At any rate, for a small operation like this it's perfect. Many people also assert it's faster however I've found that to be only slightly.

Comment: +1 But with Powershell 3 (circa June 2012) the `foreach` statement no longer steps into `$null`, so the error described by OP no longer occurs. See the section *"ForEach statement does not iterate over $null"* in the Powershell Blog post [New V3 Language Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a solution by running the query twice, once to get the files and once to count the files by casting the get-ChilItem to return an array (casting $backups as an array after the fact doesn't seem to work).
At least it works as expected (performance shouldn't be as issue since there'll never be more than a dozen files), if anyone knows of a single-query solution, please post it.

```
$count = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFilepath | 
                Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-$DaysKeep)) -and (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -like $partial + "*")}).count;

if ($count -gt 0)
{
    $backups = Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFilepath | 
                Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-$DaysKeep)) -and (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -like $partial + "*")};

    foreach ($file in $backups)
    {
        Remove-Item $file.FullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited the post for efficiency as it was easier than explaining in the comments. Just revert it if you don't like it.

Comment: @Dan - Doh, can't believe I didn't spot that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to evaluate if the array has any contents:

```
if($backups.count -gt 0) { echo "Array has contents" } else { echo "Array is empty" }
```

If the variable doesn't exist Powershell will simply evaluate it as false, so no need to check if it exists.

Comment: Adding if ($backups.count -gt 0) stops the loop executing even when there's 1 item in $backups. $backups.count even on it's own doesn't output anything.

Comment: @SteB Ah, I guess count isn't implemented for whatever object type is holding the data. I scan read and presumed it was an array.

Comment: $count = @($backups).count; almost works, but when there are no files if f($count -gt 0) is true!